# What variety of green beans make the best pickled green beans?

Tags: vegetables, pickling

I grow bush and pole bean of various varieties, mostly to make pickled green beans. I want to find a variety to grow that is string - free, long and straight, bright green, with good flavor. I like my pickled beans to be crispy.

Comment: Geoff had some of your pickled green beans on hand when I visited him last October - they were amazing!  I'd have to say the ones you grew are just fine.

Comment: I think I have been experimenting too much with "new to me" varieties. Lately they have been either too stringy, too broad, not green enough or not straight enough. I'm hoping to find the very best kind to plant next year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tradition has been to use the Blue Lake variety for canning and pickling, even though Kentucky Wonder is judged as having a fuller flavor.  One has to be careful with Blue Lake, as it is being bread for easy mechanical harvesting, with less attention being paid to flavor, according to the [UCSC Agrecology Center](http://www.escholarship.org/uc/item/5c20h3qs).

When I grow stuff, I buy my seeds from Burpee.  The [customer favorites list](http://www.burpee.com/product/productListing.jsp?catId=3000&pageNum=0&pageSize=6&facetTrail=favorites%3A1&sort=default) for snap peas (what they are now calling string beans, as the string is gone in many varieties) lists a stringless cross between Blue Lake and Kentucky.  That would be my choice for a pickle.  I would try to grow them slowly by not overwatering, as that increases the calcium content of the plant and how well the beans keep their texture submerged in a jar.

Comment: Thanks! I bought some blue lake, after not being happy with the results of the beans I grew. I'll take your advice next year on watering more gradually.